# Adjust horizontal space for 'inline' description*

Tags: description, inline, horizontal-spacing

I wanted to add an inline description as shown in the MWE. I noticed a bigger horizontal space between the optional argument and argument of \item. I've tried quite a view things like labelsep etc., but nothing showed any effect.
Is there a way to adjust the horizontal space for inline descriptions?

I use LuaLaTeX for compiling!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Das Molekulargewicht wurde auf \url{https://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/dna_mw.html} berechnet.
Unter Verwendung des NEB-Calculators (\url{https://nebiocalculator.neb.com/#!/ligation}) mit den Angaben:
\begin{description*}
    \item[Insert DNA length]1443\,bp,
    \item[Vector DNA length]5,1\,kbp und
    \item[Vector DNA mass]160\,ng.
\end{description*}
Die Lösung mit dem amplifizierten Vektor wird auf \qty{160}{\ng\per\ul} verdünnt. Da die Konzentrationen der Genfragmente bei \approx \qty{60}{ng\per\ul} liegen, werden folgende Volumina verwendet:

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example does not work, because `\approx` needs math mode.

Comment: Off-topic: For better paragraph breaking you should declare the language and therefore use, e.g., `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: Didn't know \approx needs math mode. Didn't encounter any problems so far, but good to know!

Comment: `\approx` is depending on the TeX engine. With pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX you'd get an error because of missing `$`. With LuaLaTeX there is indeed no error. Nevertheless, I recommend to use `\approx` (and other math chars) only in math mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline description lists with long labels are always problematic, because the labels are boxed and therefore do not break across lines. So the best result with your example would IMHO be:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Das Molekulargewicht wurde auf \url{https://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/dna_mw.html} berechnet.
Unter Verwendung des NEB-Calculators (\url{https://nebiocalculator.neb.com/#!/ligation}) mit den Angaben:
\begin{description*}[mode=unboxed,afterlabel={\ }]
    \item[Insert DNA length]1443\,bp,
    \item[Vector DNA length]5,1\,kbp und
    \item[Vector DNA mass]160\,ng.
\end{description*}
Die Lösung mit dem amplifizierten Vektor wird auf \qty{160}{\ng\per\ul} verdünnt. Da die Konzentrationen der Genfragmente bei $\approx \qty{60}{ng\per\ul}$ liegen, werden folgende Volumina verwendet:

\end{document}
```

A somehow better result could be reached not to using an inline list:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\topic}{\textbf}

\begin{document}

Das Molekulargewicht wurde auf \url{https://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/dna_mw.html} berechnet.
Unter Verwendung des NEB-Calculators (\url{https://nebiocalculator.neb.com/#!/ligation}) mit den Angaben:
\topic{Insert DNA length} 1443\,bp, \topic{Vector DNA length} 5,1\,kbp und
\topic{Vector DNA mass} 160\,ng.
Die Lösung mit dem amplifizierten Vektor wird auf \qty{160}{\ng\per\ul} verdünnt. Da die Konzentrationen der Genfragmente bei $\approx \qty{60}{ng\per\ul}$ liegen, werden folgende Volumina verwendet:

\end{document}
```

You can do something similar with `enumitem`, if you patch the internal command `\enit@noboxitem` to also not box the label:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifunboxlabel
\xpatchcmd{\enit@noboxitem}{\mbox}{\ifunboxlabel\else\mbox\fi}{}{\undefined}
\makeatother
\SetLabelAlign{unboxed}{\unboxlabeltrue #1}

\begin{document}

Das Molekulargewicht wurde auf \url{https://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/dna_mw.html} berechnet.
Unter Verwendung des NEB-Calculators
(\url{https://nebiocalculator.neb.com/#!/ligation}) mit den Angaben:
\unboxlabeltrue
\begin{description*}[mode=unboxed,afterlabel={\ },align=unboxed]
    \item[Insert DNA length]1443\,bp,
    \item[Vector DNA length]5,1\,kbp und
    \item[Vector DNA mass]160\,ng.
\end{description*}
Die Lösung mit dem amplifizierten Vektor wird auf \qty{160}{\ng\per\ul}
verdünnt. Da die Konzentrationen der Genfragmente bei $\approx \qty{60}{ng\per\ul}$ liegen, werden folgende Volumina verwendet:

\end{document}
```

Please, feel free to do a corresponding feature request to `enumitem`, e.g., for an option `mode=allunboxed`.

BTW: You can and should use `siunitx` also to define new units like `bp`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To define a newcommand sure is the easiest way :D

Comment: Can you suggest another package similar to enumitem, that's easier to set up?

Comment: IMHO `enumitem` is the best list package. The problem is only with inline description, because of the boxed labels. Maybe you can make a feature request for a option with unboxed labels, something like `mode=allunboxed` instead of `mode=unboxed`.

Comment: @KonstantinWeigmann See also my third suggestion, that uses `enumitem`.

Comment: @KonstantinWeigmann BTW: “Thank you” on TeX.SX would be to vote for (and maybe accept) the answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote yet. But sure will do!